# Prevent error console from appearing using .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have created an exe file using autopy to exe.

At the beginning, I ask the user to enter the file to use using the following code:

```
filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file to convert")
```

But when the user click on "Cancel" or hit the "X" in the upper right side, an error code appear as you can see on the image

[image: Error Code]

how to stop the code from continue running if the user click one of the two option mentioned above so that the error code will not appear?

I know some questions have already been asked about similar subject but I couldn't adapt them to my case. I hope I have been clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the `FileNotFoundError` is that it cannot find the file with an empty string path, which it will never find that one.

I will elaborate on what @Sagitario has explained. The `os.path.exists(filename)` used to check if the `filename` is valid and exists or not:

```
import os

if os.path.exists(filename):
    do_something() # like trying to open a file in this condition.
else:
    print(f"{filename} not found, please select other path")
```

Nevertheless, if your path is empty, it will surely go in an else condition. Instead, you can check the path input that it's not empty and exists.

In addition, the try-except block can help handle the error here. But you also need to solve the main problem of an empty file path somewhere in your code, by using the above if condition to verify the file path.

```
try:
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file to convert")
    # ...  the rest of your code relating the file opening ...
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(f"{filename} not found, please select other path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the provided path exists with `os.path.exists(filename)`

Comment: Can you be more specific please? i do not really understand how it will help me solve the problem